# AttributeError на строке 15: 'str' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input()
meth = input()
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def play(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is playing')
    def ff(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is fast forward')
    def rew(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is rewind')
    def stop(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is stop')
    if meth == 'play':
        name.play()
    elif meth == 'ff':
        name.ff()
    elif meth == 'rew':
        name.rew()
    elif meth == 'stop':
        name.stop()
```

Comment: Здесь написано что попало, перечитывайте учебники

Comment: Ваш комментарий отмечен как самый информативный, получите распишитесь;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам надо чуть больше почитать про классы в python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Вы не совсем правильно его используете.
Это исправленная ваша программа:

```
name = input()
meth = input()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def play(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is playing')
    def ff(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is fast forward')
    def rew(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is rewind')
    def stop(self, name):
        return print(name, 'is stop')
pl = Player(name)
if meth == 'play':
    pl.play(name)
elif meth == 'ff':
    pl.ff(name)
elif meth == 'rew':
    pl.rew(name)
elif meth == 'stop':
    pl.stop(name)
```

Но лучше сделать так:

```
name = input()
meth = input()
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def play(self):
        return print(self.name, 'is playing')
    def ff(self):
        return print(self.name, 'is fast forward')
    def rew(self):
        return print(self.name, 'is rewind')
    def stop(self):
        return print(self.name, 'is stop')
    def logic(self, meth):
        if meth == 'play':
            self.play()
        elif meth == 'ff':
            self.ff()
        elif meth == 'rew':
            self.rew()
        elif meth == 'stop':
            self.stop()
pl = Player(name)
pl.logic(meth)
```

Comment: приветствую! благодарю за внимание!) просто хотел реализовать ввод имени и метода и тупил насчет того, что если я условия внутри класса без отступов сделаю, то они внешними по отношению к классу окажутся, а хотелось бы внутри)...

Comment: @vladionair  Тогда просто можно сделать еще один метод и положить всю логику в него. Тогда она будет "внутри" класса.

Comment: уже интересней! а потом в метод логики вложить методы плеера. спс за наводку!

Comment: @vladionair я поправил второй вариант с внутренней логикой.

Comment: принял! черт... и списывать неохота, и ни добавить ни убавить...)))

Comment: @vladionair Ну так примите ответ. ) Сделайте приятно людям и мне )

Comment: не раздумывая) хорошего дня!)